# How does QML treat boolean opacity values?

Tags: floating-point, boolean, qml, implicit-conversion

I've come across some declarative QML code that sets the opacity for a control by using a boolean value thusly:

```
opacity: index <= maxindex
```

Now this *appears* to work but I can find nothing in the QML documentation that shows implicit conversions between the boolean value given and the real value expected by `opacity`.

[This page](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) cover the basic types and conversion between QML and C++ but appears not to detail boolean-to-real conversion within QML itself:

I'm *assuming* it follows the same "true is one, false is zero" mentality of so many other languages but I am unsure.

I may well end up changing it to:

```
opacity: (index <= maxindex) ? 1 : 0
```

since that better indicates *intent* but I'd like to know whether the implicit conversion is actually guaranteed anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt document for [QJSValue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html) refer you to [ECMA-262 specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0).

`toNumber()` method of this class should comply with [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) of ECMA-262.

> > Boolean  : If argument is true, return 1. If argument is false, return +0.

So, it should be safe to do that.